# How to calculate numerically a volume integral over a complicated 3D shape in Python?

Tags: definite-integrals, numerical-methods, python

I want to compute the volume integral $\iiint_V f(x,y,z) \ dV$ over [this volume $V$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5kp9.png). The volume is a cylinder whose base has a stadium-like shape (it is a rectangle with semi-circles at the ends). Although I can evaluate $f(x,y,z)$ for every point $(x,y,z)$ in space and that the shape itself is relatively simple, I couldn't find a way to write down analitically the limits of integration for $x$, $y$ and $z$ (or for any other common coordinates such as spherical or cylindrical) because the origin lies outside the volume (and I can't just move the origin for a more suitable position because of other reasons).

Therefore, I really think the only way is to do it numerically. It's the first time I face this isssue, but I would like to do it in Python. I searched for Python modules and the standard one seems to be scipy.integrate (I guess Numpy also has similar functions), but the functions require the limits of integration, which I can't specify.

So, are there Python tools/packages that allow me to do the integral without explicitly passing the limits of integration? For example, if I could create a 3D mesh and discretize the shape into small volume elements, then I believe that would work, as long as I knew the position of each element belonging to the shape.

Comment: If the base of the cylinder is a rectangle with two semicircles, you can start by splitting the integral in three regions. I suggest you write more details about the volume $V$. You can also do a MonteCarlo type of integration

Comment: What’s the origin got to do with it? If the base is semicircles on a rectangle $[a,b]\times [c,d]$ and the height is $h$ then your circles have radius $r=(b-a)/2$ and centers of $x$-coordinate $k=(a+b)/2$ and you’re looking at $\int_0^h\int_a^b\int_{c-\sqrt{r^2-(x-k)^2}}^{d+\sqrt{r^2-(x-k)^2}} f(x,y,z)dydxdz$, no?